# Connecting Arduino designed fingerprint scanner to Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: arduino, serial-port, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I have KOOKYE fingerprint scanner

Device:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B019TPP1UK/ref=s9_simh_gw_g147_i1_r?ie=UTF8&fpl=fresh&pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=desktop-1&pf_rd_r=0SHK4RN0THZ4NGT6PR3G&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=026d359a-cb34-4790-9249-ec9f152ee8e2&pf_rd_i=desktop

I want to connect it to Raspberry Pi 3, but the only library available for this device is for Arduino. 
Library: 
http://kookye.com/2016/07/24/use-arduino-drive-fingerprint-sensor/

Which is the best way to use the scanner on raspberry pi? Do I need to rewrite the library or I can use an Arduino emulator on Pi? If an emulator is used, how do you make the emulator to listen to the Serial port of the Arduino and which would be better to use?

Comment: Rather use an Arduino, which is easiest for 5V Signals anyway.
"Rewrite" the library in gnu-c is second easiest, I think.

Comment: I do not want to use an Arduino - not part of the plan.

Comment: You asked for the best way - and that is definitely the best way. Rewriting the library will not be a trivial task. Arduino's mesh nicely with Raspberry Pis

Comment: Very little reseacrh came up with nice discussion of same topic at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40285/use-arduino-code-on-raspberry-pi

Comment: Rewriting the library is not that complicated. It's just Rx/Tx serial communication. Other Arduino specific stuff is not involved. Not sure if the finger scanner works on raspbi 3V signals. The other line certainly needs a level reducing voltage divider.

Comment: On the manufacturer page it is stated that works with all devices that support TTL serial communication so it should be fine.